# Keeping record on same page using ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm developing a simple windows application that contains a few reports developed using report viewer control. One of my reports' template is below:

```
1) Question1? 
a) Choise11 
b) Choise12 
c) Choise13 
d) Choise14

2) Question2? 
a) Choise21 
b) Choise22 
c) Choise23 
d) Choise24
.
.
.
.
```

I want to prevent page breaks in the middle of questions. I mean, I want to keep the question and all its choises (a, b, c, d) in the same page. Is it possible? If yes, how can I change my report settings?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Use the **KeepTogether** property on the appropriate group/details control. See the "Keeping Report Items Together on a Single Page" section on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255248%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Note that this feature can behave buggy from time to time, e.g. see [this highly upvoted Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/428595/keep-together-property-not-working-in-ssrs-2008).